# Remove "Via" response header from "ledge"

Tags: nginx, proxy, http-headers, openresty

I have an Openresty web-server that is also working as caching server by using [ledge](https://github.com/ledgetech/ledge). ledge is setting a "Via" response header that exposing the hostname of the server which is fqdn.

```
Via: 1.1 xyz.example.com
```

I have these in my openresty and ledge config:

```
more_clear_headers 'Server';
server_tokens off;
```

I would like to remove the "Via" response header completely. But unable to figure out how to do it on ledge :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out and it's a simple one. Has nothing to do with ledge. Just added 'Via' in more_clear_headers rule.

```
more_clear_headers 'Server' 'Via';
```